# How to Calculate Average Time between Dates in CSV File with multiple column in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file with three different columns, namely Year, Month and Day.
If I printed it out, it will be something like below:

```
csv_reader = [['2016', '6', '22'], ['2016', '10', '2'], ['2016', '11', '1'], ['2016', '11', '3'], ['2016', '11', '3'], ['2016', '11', '17'], ['2016', '11', '17'], ['2016', '11', '17'], ['2016', '12', '2'], ['2016', '12', '12'], ['2016', '12', '22'], ['2016', '12', '22'], ['2017', '1', '11'], ['2017', '3', '11'], ['2017', '3', '11'], ['2017', '5', '12'], ['2017', '5', '12'], ['2017', '5', '12']]
```

So both the csv file and the row are lists.
I want to **calculate the average days between each date** from this dataset. I try to use:

```
from datetime import date
for value in csv_reader:
    dates = date(int(value))
    differences = [(dates[i]-dates[i-1]).days for i in range(1, len(dates))]
print(float(sum(differences))/len(differences))
```

But it returned an error stating that

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

and I suspect if my code is actually correct.
The expected result should calculate the sum of difference between each dates, and then divided by the total differences, which would return the average days.
So, could any of you give advice on how to perform this task?

Comment: What is `csv_reader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have

```
csv_reader = [['2016', '6', '22'], ['2016', '10', '2'], ['2016', '11', '1'], ['2016', '11', '3'], ['2016', '11', '3'], ['2016', '11', '17'], ['2016', '11', '17'], ['2016', '11', '17'], ['2016', '12', '2'], ['2016', '12', '12'], ['2016', '12', '22'], ['2016', '12', '22'], ['2017', '1', '11'], ['2017', '3', '11'], ['2017', '3', '11'], ['2017', '5', '12'], ['2017', '5', '12'], ['2017', '5', '12']]
```

first, to get a valid date from lets say, the first item, you need to covert the str to int, and only then call `date`:

```
date(*[int(d) for d in csv_reader[0]])
```

And you need to have a `date` instance for each 2 dates and subtract them:

```
date(*[int(d) for d in csv_reader[0]]) - date(*[int(d) for d in csv_reader[1]])
```

Afterwards, you get a `timedelta` object, which has `.days`. Sometimes it'll be negative, so you'll need to use the absolute value, with `abs`.

After you sum all those days, you need to do the average, relative to the number of elements.

All in all, this is the loop you need:

```
total = 0
for i in range(len(csv_reader)-1):  
    total += abs((date(*[int(d) for d in csv_reader[i]]) - date(*[int(d) for d in csv_reader[i+1]])).days)

>>> total
324
>>> total / len(csv_reader)
18
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert list of str to the list of dates

   ```
   dates = [datetime.date(*[int(d) for d in ds]) for ds in sortedtime]
   ```
2. Zip two lists of dates with shift for 1 day and calculate timedelta of days:

   ```
   delta_days = [(d_t[0] - d_t[1]).days for d_t in list(zip(dates[1:],dates))]
   ```
3. The Average will be a simple operation

   ```
   avg_days = sum(delta_days)/len(delta_days)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert this string `'2016,6,22'` to int. You should delete commas before you pass a string into the int() function

Comment: I try to use  dates = date(int(row.strip(" .,:;?!’[]()"))  but it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `date(int(value))` into `date(int(value.replace(',','')))`.

Comment: It returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Oh, right, now you edited your question it seems normal. What is the expected result?